# Video is not scaling properly on mobile device

Tags: css, html, video, scale

I have embedded a video in a DIV and want it to scale according to the size of the browser (up to a certain point).
This all works fine, but on an iPhone, the scaling doesn't work.

Here is a live link that works:
http://www.craigzilla.dk/upload/template.html

And here is a screenshot of how it looks on an iPhone where the video isn't scaled up to fit horizontally:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xs2fex89td710ip/Photo%2005-09-13%2016.11.14.png

And here is a jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/EWgFm/

Here is the video css:

```
.projectWrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: auto;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas how I can force the video to fill out the horizontal space?

Comment: Did you try `video {
    width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: Not sure, I can't replicate in my browser. I assume it's an iPhone thing. Do you have a min-height set somewhere? That would explain it, well, if it did it everywhere.

Comment: video { width: 100% !important; } doesn't make a difference.
and I haven't got ant min-heights anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

CSS:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,  
.video-container object,  
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/6284199?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/elastic-videos/)**